# Trouble with d3 zoom transform. Error: [ts] Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add zoom, but am failing miserably. I have a container for the zoom:

```
        this.container = svg.append("g");
```

and this:

```
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", function () {
                alert("here")
                this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
                alert("here 2");
            });
```

and this call:

```
       .call(zoom);
```

The transform part ... `this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")` ...
is causing me a problem. It gives me this error: `[ts] Property 'translate' does not exist on type 'Event | BaseEvent'`. And won't compile.

If I change the `d3.event.translate` and `d3.event.scale` to `(<any>d3.event).translate` and `(<any>d3.event).scale`, or to `(<any>d3).event.translate` and `(<any>d3).event.scale`, the error goes away, but the zoom doesn't work.

With those `<any>` changes incorporated, when I double-click my mouse or scroll (the first time) I get my first alert. I never make it to my second alert.

I'm pretty sure the problem is with this line: `this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")`. How can I fix it?

I'm using TypeScript and d3 v3.5.5 to build a Power BI custom visual.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here are the parts of what worked for me:

I added this at the start of the visual's class...after the part that says "export class [VISUAL'S NAME (e.g., scatterChart)] implements IVisual {":

```
        private container: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
```

I added this in the 'constructor' as a wrapper:

```
        this.container = svg.append("g");
```

The rest of this, I put in 'update'.

This, I believe, is referred to as a 'listener':

```
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", this.zoomed.bind(this));
```

Here's the call to zoom.

```
        this.svg.call(zoom);
```

And this is the 'zoomed' function, which does the zoom and pan:

```
    private zoomed() {
        this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + ((<any>d3.event).translate) + ")scale(" + ((<any>d3.event).scale) + ")");}
```

You can see I still used basically the same line that I thought was the problem (`this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + ((<any>d3.event).translate) + ")scale(" + ((<any>d3.event).scale) + ")");`. It turned out that the *real* problem was that I needed to add the `.bind(this)` in the call to `zoomed`.